# SpringBoot: Destroy bean after last use / initialization phase

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, destructor

I have a `Closeable` bean that I only use during initialization of the application, but not later. It opens a resource that is used during initialization. I would like the `close` method to be called as early as possible after the last use of the object. Is it possible to auto-destroy objects.

### Example

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class InitHelper implements Closeable {
  public InitHelper() {
    log.debug("Initialized InitHelper");
  }
  public int hello() {
    return 42;
  }
  @PreDestroy
  public void close() {
    log.debug("Closed InitHelper");
  }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean
  public A a(InitHelper initHelper) {
    return new A(initHelper.hello());
  }

  @Bean
  public B b(InitHelper initHelper) {
    return new A(initHelper.hello());
  }
}
```

### Expected behavior

A `InitHelper` bean gets initialized before `A` and `B` and destroyed after `a` and `b` were completed.

### Actual behavior

The `InitHelper.close` method is not called on its instance.

Comment: You can listen for context event and close your bean when context is ready. I dont think(but do not know neither) that spring will figure out that it can be closed for you

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks, that works. If you like, you can post an answer. Otherwise, I'll post an answer by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Antoniossss mentioned in the comments, listening for the `ApplicationReadyEvent` is a possible solution. I implemented it as follows:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void closeMyResource(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
  InitHelper initHelper = event.getApplicationContext().getBean(InitHelper.class);
  initHelper.close();
}
```